# Is it possible to have separate output settings for preview/final renders?

Tags: animation, file-format

For animation, I have the final output render to a PNG Sequence.
I want to use the viewport animation feature to test my animation.
Is there a way to have this independently set to render to an animation file such as mp4?

Comment: Hi. Do you mean that you would like separate output settings for preview/final renders?

Comment: I was a bit long-winded, but, yes!

Comment: Is that possible?